# Fuzzy file listing matches

Tags: bash, find, sh, fuzzy-search

I'm wondering if there is a way to take a file listing and pass it through a fuzzy matching algorithm on the command line.

For example, in a listing of a few hundred files I might have

```
Journal.2012-Nov-13.pdf
Journal 2012 Nov 13.pdf
Journal 2012-Nov-13-backup (3).pdf
```

and I'd like those to 'match' out of the hundreds of files.

Of course, the similar named may be more like

```
The Great Gatsby.pdf
The Great Gatsby (1925).epub
```

so obviously the tool would need to have a certain amount of customization for 'how fuzzy' to match filenames.

Ideally I could pipe a single ls and get back a list of files that were close matches.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "fuzzy"?  Do you mean partial matches (e.g. "atsby" would match both in your example), or do you mean tolerant to different spelling (e.g. "Gtsby" would match both in your example).

Comment: Use the agrep utility

Comment: Fred: ideally both of those example would be possible matches, depending on settings.

Comment: stark: never heard of agrep, but I will check it out, thanks